# How to match URL with regex number?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match a URL which it can be generated with any random numbers, for example, these urls:

```
www.domain.com/products/id?=292
www.domain.com/products/id?=132
www.domain.com/products/id?=698
```

There a code to compare URL with random number is equal, this currently code won't work.

```
var url1= "www.domain.com/products/id?=292";
var url2= "www.domain.com/products/id?=7542";
var url3= "www.domain.com/products/id?=5401";


var numberPat = /[0-9]/;    

    if(url3 ==  "www.domain.com/products/id?=" + numberPat){ 
        alert("Domain with random number is MATCHED")
    }
    else{
        alert("Domain with random number is NOT matched")
    }
```

I made a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/n5s2pvkr/1/ Im looking a solution that could return as true with matched url with random number

**EDIT: I cannot accept url3.match(numberPat) for some reason, I need to do exactly like:**

***www.domain.com/products/id?=+numberPat*** **due to selective comparison.**

Comment: I would extract the value (by getting text after *=*) then do a isNaN to see if they are numbers. No need for regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use repetition in your regex `/\d+/` to match more than one digit.

Also, why are you trying to add a regex to a String?

If you want to check the URL, you're probably looking for

`url1.match(/^www\.domain\.com\/products\/id\?=\d+$/)`

1. `^` Start at the beginning
2. `www\.domain\.com\/products\/id\?=` find this exact string
3. `\d+` find any number of digits
4. `$` must be end of string

http://jsfiddle.net/n5s2pvkr/3/

```
var url1= "www.domain.com/products/id?=292";
var url2= "www.domain.com/products/id?=7542";
var url3= "www.domain.com/products/id?=5401";

function isMatch(url) {
    if(url.match(/^www\.domain\.com\/products\/id\?=\d+$/)){ 
        return "Domain with random number is MATCHED";
    }
    else{
        return "Domain with random number is NOT matched";
    }
}

alert([url1, url2, url3].map(function(url) {
    return isMatch(url);
}).join('\n'));
```

**Edit**:

Reading your question again, I think you were shooting matching the digits of the URL then comparing it like

```
if (url3 == "www.domain.com/products/id?=" + url3.match(/\d+/))`
```

which is a little redundant since you could just match on the static part of the string as well.

Code with fewest modifications: http://jsfiddle.net/n5s2pvkr/4/

```
var url1= "www.domain.com/products/id?=292";
var url2= "www.domain.com/products/id?=7542";
var url3= "www.domain.com/products/id?=5401";


var numberPat = /[0-9]+/;    

if(url3 ==  "www.domain.com/products/id?=" + url3.match(numberPat)){ 
    alert("Domain with random number is MATCHED")
}
else{
    alert("Domain with random number is NOT matched")
}
```

Comment: It actually worked what I excepted, thank you for reading my reason!

Answer (score 2):

As I suggested in my comment you can do this without regex:

```
var url2= "www.domain.com/products/id?=7542";
var url3= "www.domain.com/products/id?=5401";

if (isNaN(url2.split("=")[1]) == false) {
    alert("Is number.");   
} else {
    alert("NAN");   
}
```

**Note:** this will break if you have multiple keys.

**Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/dxyt8Ldm/

Comment: It didn't help me because it only needs to match ...products/id?=234, not ...profile/id?=234, ...store/id?=234, ...promotion/id?=234

Answer (score 2):

To build your regex dynamically use `new RegExp(...)` like this:

```
var url1= "www.domain.com/products/id?=292";
var url2= "www.domain.com/products/id?=7542";
var url3= "www.domain.com/products/id?=5401";
numberPat = '[0-9]+';

// build your regex here
var re = new RegExp("www\\.domain\\.com/products/id\\?=" + numberPat)

// now test it
re.test(url3)
true
re.test(url2)
true
re.test(url1)
true
```

Comment: Not sure how you tried. If you copy/paste above code in JsFiddle it will work fine.